# Firebase cloud messaging service doesn't show notifications(google says it's sent)

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have to make an android app. Through that app I am trying to send/receive push notifications with firebase but for some reason I am not able to do that.

Is there a problem on my code which you can point? Or is there a way to receive the notifications on android console or something to check if there is anything wrong  with my emulator's notifications? Because google says it has sent but I am out of ideas besides that way. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

After various different examples(most of them not working after targeting sdk>26) I have managed to implement some code. But even after a lot of tries, my emulator doesn't show the notifications which are sent from firebase console(foreground or background). I believe I made it everything right considering the number of examples and versions I have encountered.

**EDIT** I have managed to send notifications on chrome(i was using opera). About my latter question, is there a way I can see these notifications on log or console?(in order to handle each notification for specific user I believe I need some parameters to play around )

**EDIT 2(Solved)**  The problem was there also because of the google's firebase services, it has a considerable delay sometimes. Also you have to get confirming tick on both android studio's tools windows for firebase and also in the firebase console.

MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
package com.example.testapplication.Service;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.testapplication.R;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

import static com.google.android.gms.common.util.WorkSourceUtil.TAG;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    Log.e("NEW_TOKEN", s);
}




@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());




    Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);
    Log.e("JSON_OBJECT", object.toString());

    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Nilesh_channel";

    long pattern[] = {0, 1000, 500, 1000};

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Your Notifications",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        notificationChannel.setDescription("");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(pattern);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    // to diaplay notification in DND Mode
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        channel.canBypassDnd();
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setAutoCancel(true);


    mNotificationManager.notify(1000, notificationBuilder.build());
}

private void showNotification(String title, String body) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example";

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,"Notification",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.setDescription("plandigittest");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,1000});
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentInfo("Info");
    notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

App gradle
{

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.testapplication"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Project gradle
{

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common 
to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {                                  // <-- Add this
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

}Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testapplication" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".Service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: Check your internet connection on your mobile phone?

Comment: No issues there of course. I edited my question but left it all there in case someone may encounter later. My current problem is to send notifications to a specific user. I think I can do it via inspecting received notification so maybe I can send it properly? Thanks anyway

Comment: you specified that you are testing in emulator, So check once in real device. May be the issue is device token. Notification are always sent to device tokens.